# How to store key/value in Interface Builder and access them during runtime?

Tags: ios, interface-builder

I would like to store a help text for some of my UIViews of various type (set in the interface builder) and access them during runtime to display them to the user. Is that possible? I understood that user defined runtime attributes can only be used if they exist as UIView's property. Is there another way?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Interface Builder designable macro for it.

Create your custom class called, for example `TestViewClass`, and define property with `IBInspectable`.

Set custom class to some `UIView` in Interface Builder, and then you will see that you can set that property via IB [image]

```
IB_DESIGNABLE
@interface TestViewClass : UIView

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBInspectable NSString *helpText;

@end
```